Tailscale, Caddy https and a sub-domain: wildcard domain
I've just got Caddy to issue an https certifcate for my tailscale network, following their tutorials. Very easy.
But I was hoping the tailscale caddy system would issue a wildcard domain cert, and looking at the certificate there is no mention it is such.
Am I wrong?
It seems a waste of resources to create a tailscale-caddy server for each of my internal services.
I don't think it helps if I fall back to tailscale cert to manage the certs, it's still one tailscale-caddy server for each internal service
